# Consume SSRS Report within Windows Service

Tags: reporting-services, windows-services, ssrs-2008

I want to consume a SSRS report within a windows service (wrote in C#). The service will then export the report as a PDF and write it to disk.

Is this even possible? I am new to SSRS.

Comment: Mick, what is that you are trying to achieve here i have an idea , i am only asking as you said you are new to SSRS and there would be another way to do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is generate the report passing in a guid parameter, and then save the output to a PDF.

Comment: ok and will this GUID be always the same? or atleast there will be set of GUIDs which will be the same? is this kind of on-demand PDF generation or you can produce the PDF at a set time which you can determine?

Comment: The guid coresponds to the primary key of a record in a table which is used in the underlying query of the report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting  question Mick. We have done code where we can call the SSRS report and export it as PDF but that code is in DLL. Now windows service is no different I would advise you to go through the following code http://sandeep-aparajit.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/how-to-execute-and-save-ssrs-report.html and try the same. It should work as far as i can see the only problem you might come across might be Code access security  but it is worth a try. Thanks for the question you have given me an idea.

The URL for Reporting services will depend on what version  of SSRS you are using but as you can see you can easily spot and change it http:///reportserver/reportservice2005.asmx instead of 2005 you might have to change to 2008 or something.